# VS 2012 intellisense - function may not be initialized

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I'm just playing around a little bit with decltype and noticed the intellisense in VS 2012 is giving me a error. This is the first time I have encountered this and the code still compiled.

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int param)
{
    std::cout << "IM BEING CALLED: " << param << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto& y = func;
    auto z = func;

    decltype((func))& x = func;
    decltype((func)) k = func; // function 'k' may not be initialized but compiles


    func(9);
    x(10);
    y(11);
    z(12);
    k(13);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Address of func: " << func << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of x: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of y: " << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Address of z: " << z << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "Address of k: " << k << std::endl; 

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This is not a major problem nor interesting for most people but I was just wondering if anyone knows the reason behind the error?

Comment: IntelliSense does have bugs. Example: I have a function `MyFunction` that is a friend of the class `MyClass`. IntelliSense marks usages of private members of `MyClass` in `MyFunction` as errors (not warnings), even though the code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: I think you should remove the last part of your question as that's a list question. The main bulk of it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering if anyone knows the reason behind the error

It's just a parsing bug. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: cheers mate, was confused first and though there was something wrong with the code until i compiled it.